# Can someone help me, to compute by hand $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a $5\times5$ Matrix and $b=(1,1,1,1,1)$ transposed

Tags: matrices

Using Cholesky decomposition i have L and L transposed,how can i solve $Ax=b$ without using inverses?

$A$ is a $5\times 5$ Matrix
$b=(1,1,1,1,1)^t$

Another question, How would you easily compute the inverse of matrix A?
I would be grateful for any suggestion.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0):

In general, given an LU (lower/upper triangular) decomposition, associativity of matrix multiplication gives us:
$$Ax = (LU)x = L(Ux) = b.$$
Defining $y:= Ux$ allows us to first solve:
$$Ly = b,$$
which is easy (start in the top row, solve for the first variable and work your way down substituting each result). Once you have the vector value for $y$, you can solve $Ux=y$ for $x$ in a similar manner starting instead at the bottom. This is particularly true in the case of Cholesky, where the matrices happen to be transposes of each other.

A good reference for this type of thing is Ch.8 of Kendall Atkinson's *Introduction to Numerical Analysis*.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This question goes against our [quality standard policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508). Instead of posting an answer, you should encourage the person who posted the question to improve it.